# Why'd a 1080p video playing on 1366x768 resolution screen show black bars?

Tags: video, resolution, vlc-media-player, video-playback

[image: VLC Video Properties]

Above is a screenshot of the properties of the video I played in VLC. As you can see, it clearly shows that the video is 1080p.

But when I am playing the video on my Windows laptop (with a 1366x768 resolution screen), I see black bars. Isn't the video supposed to be played in full screen, without any black bars, as both the video and my screen have a 16:9 resolution? What am I missing here?

**Screenshot of video playing:**

[image: Video playing screenshot]

Comment: The video is being played full screen without black bars. Those black regions you see are part of the video which was likely made from an even wider theater-format original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movie is wider than 16:9 and the letterbox black bars are encoded into the video file.